# Vitest importActual: Jest gets types, but Vitest gives "... is of type unknown"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite, vitest

I'm migrating from jest to vitest. In the process, I am converting these:

```
// Jest
const myLib = jest.requireActual("mylib.js")
```

to these:

```
// Vitest
const myLib = await vi.importActual("myLib.js")
```

Great, except with Jest, I get no type errors, but with Vitest, I get:

`TS18046: myLib is of type unknown`

I can access members of `myLib`, and I can see that they are typed correctly, but any access on `myLib` causes the error:

```
// Thing[] is inferred. Error is on **myLib**.things
const things: Thing[] = myLib.things
```

When investigating (by simply hovering over `myLib` in WebStorm) the type in each scenario, I see that Jest gives `any` for `myLib`'s type, while Vitest gives `unknown`.

I have `noImplicitAny: true` in my tsconfig.json, so I would think I should get an error on `any` as well.

But anyway, why is there a difference, how can TypeScript figure out that `myLib.things` is of type `Thing[]` if `myLib` itself is `unknown`, and how am I supposed to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I guess a simple way to deal with this is to simply do `await vi.importActual("myLib.js") as Record<{a: b}>`, where `a` is some member you're accessing within the test and `b` is the type of that member. `unknown` may be better than `any` here since it forces you to be aware of this.

However, I still don't understand how `Thing[]` could possibly be inferred from `unknown`.